# How to set several columns as the key in data.table package (r)?

Tags: r, data.table

`setkey()` can be used to set a column as the key to a data table. 
But now I have three column:

```
A         B          C

1         2          3
1         2          4
1         2          5
```

I want to set the ABC as the key. How to do it in `data.table` package?

Comment: According to `?setkey`:  `"The key can be any columns in any order."`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three simple alternatives:

```
# 1
setkeyv(dt, c("A","B","C"))


# 2
keycols = c("A","B","C")
setkeyv(dt, keycols)


# 3, or you can setkey for the whole data.table
setkey(data)
```

**data for example:**

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(A=c(1,1,1), B=c(2,2,2), C=c(3:5))
```

Comment: I tried, but here is the error:Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) : 
  some columns are not in the data.table: c("A", "B", "C")